Trouble detecting/removing two watermarks that vary location across image dataset
I have a problem with removing watermarks from a collection of images. The watermarks appear near each other but are different (see below). One watermark is a red square and has white text inside of it. The other is a semi-transparent grey sentence. The purpose is to process the images for machine learning purposes.
Problem solving attempts:
Because the watermarks vary in their location across the image dataset, I attempted the following:

Made a copy of the image and converted it to the HSV colorspace
Selected a range of lower and upper values for the region of interest (the values were selected after segmenting the image and constructing a histogram for each channel)
Built a mask using the cv2.inRange() function
Used the mask to in-paint the watermark in the original image

For the red square, the first three steps worked perfectly. But the third step only sort-of worked. The watermark is significantly less visible than before, but still very apparent. For the text, I was unable to get a good enough mask in step 3 - it simply is too close in color/pixel intensity to the surrounding area and the text itself.
This is looking more like a machine learning problem, which is fine, but I wanted to exhaust other options beforehand. Any thoughts on how to resolve this issue using machine learning or algorithmic methods?

share the piece of code and the output

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the help center (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example - And Show Code As Text, Not An Image" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

It's more than a machine learning problem, it's a legal problem.  Those watermarks are there to protect the copyright of the image owners, and you're violating that copyright.  If you want unwatermarked images, then you should go to Archivos Estatales and ask for permission to use them.  They have the unwatermarked originals.

A simple threshold at about 35% seems to do a reasonable job. Adjust as necessary. Or just threshold on black using cv2.inRange.  But I agree with Tim Roberts about violating copyright.

This is not a legal problem. The images are owned by the group that I work for (they were purchased legally). The watermarks have to be removed for processing.

Could you @fmw42 explain what you mean by your response on thresholding on black using cv2inRange? I appreciate the response, by the way.

Use cv2.inRange() on the original image and pick a range of values around 35% black plus or minus then invert so you get black letters again. I did a simple threshold at 35% (in Imagemagick) on your input and the results looked reasonable. 35% would be 255*0.35=89 (in range 0 to 255). You could do a simple threshold after converting to grayscale and probably get something similar. The text is there, but the two watermarks seem to be gone for me.

I note that you have edited the code suggested by Fred (@fmw42) into your question. Surely that is the answer, not the question? As such, you should create an answer to your question because that is where folk expect to find solutions and can also upvote them.

Solution:
image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
lower_limit = 89  # 35% of 255, although a slightly higher percentage my increase visibility of text if that is desired
upper_limit = 255
mask = cv2.inRange(gray, lower_limit, upper_limit)

mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)

# Invert the mask_inv to get black text on white background
inverted_mask_inv = ~mask_inv

plt.subplot(1,2,1); plt.imshow(image); plt.title("Original")
plt.subplot(1,2,2); plt.imshow(inverted_mask_inv, cmap="gray"); plt.title("Just the text")


Why did you convert to grayscale?  Was the image not color?  cv2.inRange() can work directly on the input if you choose BGR values.
